# What regex can I use to validate a number between 0 and 255?

Tags: php, regex, validation, pcre

I want to validate number in range of 0-255

I have this expression

```
'/^([0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9])|([2][0-4][0-9])|(25[0-5])$/'
```

But this accepts any number...
And this works:

```
'/(^[0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9]$)|(^[2][0-4][0-9]$)|(^25[0-5]$)/'
```

why do I have to have ^ and $ for each option?

edit: I have it, but I cannot answer my question, so - `^` and `$` have higher priority than `|`, so `/^(...)$/` helped

Comment: Actually, you can answer your own question...

Comment: You really should go with @alex' answer!

Comment: It displayed me, that I can answer my own question after 7 hours or something like that, probably because I'm new here

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Note:** [@alex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560030/php-pcre-0-255-range-regex/6560038#6560038) is the way to go. Validating a number range with regex is like using a jackhammer to catch a fly.

But nevertheless I wanted to provide an explanation for this "problem".

---

You don't have to, you just have to group it correctly, which means you have to group the alternation:

```
'/^(([0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9])|([2][0-4][0-9])|(25[0-5]))$/'
// ^                                             ^
```

Otherwise the expression will be interpreted as follows (logically)

```
(^number) OR (number) OR (number$)
```

With the brackets, it will be

```
^(number OR number OR number)$
```

Comment: *...using a jackhammer to catch a fly*. I *have* to try that one day! :P

Comment: @alex: I'm not sure whether this actually good wording (me is not native English speaker ;)). I'm sure there is a proper English proverb for this. But as long as you like it I'm fine ;)

Comment: You write English better than a lot of people I know of whom it is their first language. Bravo!

Answer (score 7):

Don't use a regex for validating a number range.

Just use a condition...

```
if ($number >= 0 AND $number <= 255) {
   ...
}
```

This will ensure the number is between 0 and 255 inclusively, which is what your regex appears to be doing.

To answer your question specifically, it doesn't work because you need to wrap the whole thing with a capturing group otherwise the regex engine will do an *OR* of each individual regex...

```
/^([0-1]?[0-9]?[0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$/
```

Also note that `$` will match before any trailing `\n`. Use `\z` if you really want to match at the end of the string.

Comment: @Ivan: Convert the text to a number. You could use `intval`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php

Comment: @Felix: yeah, but I would have to use another pcre to extract number(s) from text anyway, so why not validate it in expression? Well, maybe it's much more slower....

Comment: @IvanStana: Ok, if you have a several lines text and some of the lines only contain numbers (which have to be between 0 and 255), then yes, regex is better... but if the whole string is only a number, then `intval` will do. Anyway, only you know the input, I assume you know what you do ;)

Comment: Thank you all for every answer, I think I learned something new from this :-)

Answer (score 3):

one more method (but previous solution is better I think)

```
in_array($number, range(0, 255))
```

Comment: I thought about including this in my answer, but its a bit of overhead for something very simple. Still, +1 for alternate answer :)

Answer (score 2):

I played with it further, and here is regex for strict 0-255 range, without leading zeroes permitted:

`'/^([0]|[1-9]\d?|[1]\d{2}|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))$/'`

Answer (score 1):

First off, I agree that @Alex's answer is the way to go if available; however, it may be worth mentioning that the regex version can be done with the somewhat more concise pattern:

```
/^([01]?\d{1,2}|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))$/
```

...which is what I use when numeric parsing isn't an option.

Answer (score 0):

[0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]

will work

Answer (score 0):

`^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9])|[1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-5][0-5])$` this works for 0-255 meaning no leading zeros such as 001

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been answered, but I needed a similar regex for page routing; except for the range of 1-66. This worked well: /^(?!67|68|69)[1-6][0-9]|[1-9]$/