# Simple PHP regular expressions

Tags: php, regex

Good evening, I'm learning regular expressions to PHP. I am not managing to make 1 to 30 and 1 to 10. For 1 to 9, I thought [1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9] or [1-9]{1}, which is more correct? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `[1-9]` would be correct. To get 1 to 30 you'd need something like this: `[12]?\d|30`

Comment: There's no need for {1}.

Comment: You might check the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560030/what-regex-can-i-use-to-validate-a-number-between-0-and-255

Comment: @hsan, you need to match boundaries (otherwise 100000 will match). Plus the first number would have to be optional (otherwise 6 won't match)

Comment: @EdsonMedina We don't know if the 1-30 is the whole string, surrounded by non-digits or even surrounded by digits... therefore I did not provide any kind of boundaries.

Comment: @hsan in that case, it doesn't work... 45 with match

Comment: @EdsonMedina Because there is a 4 (or a 5 whatever way you look at it...). As I said before. The context was not provided so I only suggested the part of a regex that was asked for in the question.

Comment: Oh and the regex in my first comment would actually match 0-30. `[1-9]|[12]\d|30` would match 1-30.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 1 to 9, there is straight forward regex that is `[1-9]`.
For 1 to 10, and 1 to 30, a combination of rules are to be applied.
For 1 to 10, you can use this:

```
10|[1-9]
```

For 1 to 30, this regex could be used:

```
(30)|([12][0-9])|([1-9])
```

or

```
(30)|([12]\d)|([1-9])
```

the first part `30`, would look for exact match i.e. 30.
the second part `[12]\d` or `[12][0-9]`, would look for numbers between 10 to 29.
the last part `[1-9]` would look for numbers between 1-9.

Comment: Won't work if you don't have a leading zero

Comment: it will match zero, which isn't in the range of 1-10. And `\d` is equivalent to `[0-9]` not `[1-9]`.

Answer (score 1):

The following are valid regex patterns for a single digit between 0 ad 9:

- `[0123456789]`
- `[0-9]`
- `\d`

All of the above are equivalent.

Your suggested version `[1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9]` is not correct.

To match a number between 1 and 30, Regex is not the best tool, but if you *must* use regex for it, then the simplest regex would be this:

```
([012]?\d|30)
```

But note that this will also match `0`, so it's really a 0-30 pattern.

If you really want 1-30, then it's even more complex:

```
([1-9]|[12]\d|30)
```

If the number 1-30 is the whole of the string you're looking for, then don't forget to add `^` to the start and `$` to the end of the pattern to anchor it so that it rejects strings containing 1-30 plus other characters.

I did mention that regex is the wrong tool for just matching numbers, didn't I? If you can avoid using regex for this, then it'll be much simpler for you. It's just a case of `if($var >= 1 && $var <= 30)`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: without boundaries, 50000 would match

Comment: @EdsonMedina - well, yes, but the OP didn't specify anything about whether that was the whole string or not, so I couldn't give any boundaries. I just gave the portion of the expression that would match the bit of the string he wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regular expression:

```
30|[12]?\d
```

It will match numbers between 1 and 30, without leading zeros