# Matching the first line of content in RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, numbers, match

### I want to match numbers between 0 and 799 ONLY,if it doesn't have a comma in them.

---

```
$660
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560030/what-regex-can-i-use-tovalidate-anumber-between-0-and-255
```

I've tried using **this RegEx. -->** `\b(0*(?:[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?|100))\b` and it works very well.
(If the number is between **0 and 999**)

> Need help with changing my regex:
>
> - I need it to work in JavaScript.
> - I'd like to validate the number in the first row **using regex** after the **$**  (I only need
>     It,if It's between **0 and 799**)
> - If it has a **comma** in it then it should be ignored( like numbers 799+)

- I don't want it to accept numbers with **comma** in them,because my current regex thinks it's valid.
  (Or at least the 6,245 should be equal to 6245 so my regex can ignore it.)

Comment: Could you give us some example inputs, and whether each should match or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To rephrase your question, numbers must not have a comma before them, or after:

```
(?<!,)\b[1-7]?\d?\d\b(?!,)
```

[Try it online](http://rubular.com/r/8mwEmoXkK5).

If you can't use look behinds, eg if you use JavaScript, you'll have to consume the non-comma and capture the target instead:

```
(^|[^,])(\b[1-7]?\d?\d\b(?!,))
```

The number is in group 1.

[Try it online](http://rubular.com/r/YGZn9BQJlT).

Comment: It's almost what I need,but I only want to match the first line and ignore all the other rows where are numbers. http://rubular.com/r/YssSb8JxAL   Your expression is not limited to the first row. (I only need the numbers after the $ and nothing else(only that row))

Comment: BTW I just tried using it and It says that "Lookbehind is not supported in JavaScript".(It was my fault not saying I needed it in JavaScript)