# Trying to map the 'Private IP' of my computer with python

Tags: python

I want to filter the IPv4 ips and take the one which belong to my LAN (and not to my VMware network).
I coded this thing:

```
print re.findall(r'[0-255]\.[0-255]\.[0-255]\.[0-255]', str([y for y in filter(lambda x: 'IPv4 Address' in x, os.popen("ipconfig").readlines())]))
```

This part:

```
str([y for y in filter(lambda x: 'IPv4 Address' in x, os.popen("ipconfig").readlines())])
```

Its for getting first the ips I have (At least the row they are in.)
So for example, just this row, will give me:

> ['   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.231.1\n', '   IPv4
>   Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.233.1\n', '   IPv4 Address. . .
>   . . . . . . . . : 10.100.102.8\n']

(The first two are of the VMware)

When I do the Regex thing, it isnt working. 
Its intended to give me just the ips from the string I gave it.

How can I filter the only LAN ip ('10.100.102.8' in this case.) and insert it to a string?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560030/what-regex-can-i-use-to-validate-a-number-between-0-and-255

Comment: all addresses in your LAN should start with `10.` so try `10.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}` or without regex `lambda x: 'IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.' in x`

Comment: btw: standard module [ipaddress](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html)

Comment: @furas Are you sure? Because in here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network I see there is more then just one ip type. There is actually three! the two others are starting with 192\171. so....

Comment: you ask only how to recognize `10.100.102.8`.  If you want to be sure than you have to check network adapter as @Goufalite said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Watch out! `[0-255]` isn't a number range in regex ! (in fact it means *one* character in the list 0,1,2,5)

You should use `\d{1,3}` if you want a three digit number, then extract groups if you want to check if the number is in the range.

Comment: Thank you! now. How can I know the LAN ip and throw the two other ips?

Comment: As @furas commented, make a check using your subnet domain (10....), or at least put it in a variable. But if this information changes (generic program) you might need to parse the full `ipconfig` command to check the network adapter...